# How to set the selected attribute of Select tab based on the servlet passed fields in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my web application, I am working on a screen, where I want to display retrieved data onto the screen. In my screen I have one drop down for "direction". I am setting value of this field from servlet. But I am not getting a way to display the selected option by default in the page.

```
<select name="indv_adr_mail_st_dir" value="${indv_adr_mail_st_dir}">
        <option value="EA">East</option>
        <option value="NE">North East</option>
        <option value="NO">North</option>
        <option value="NW">North West</option>
        <option value="SE">South East</option>
        <option value="SO">South</option>
        <option value="SW">South West</option>
        <option value="WE">West</option>
</select>
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesnt work is the `<select>` tags selected option is designated by placing the `selected` attribute on a specific option, not by setting the `value` attribute. For instance

```
<select name="test">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option selected value="no">No</option> <!-- this is the selected option -->
</select>
```

For your code you could make this happen by using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to optionally place the `selected` attribute on an option

```
<select name="indv_adr_mail_st_dir">
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="EA"?"selected":""} value="EA">East</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="NE"?"selected":""} value="NE">North East</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="NO"?"selected":""} value="NO">North</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="NW"?"selected":""} value="NW">North West</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="SE"?"selected":""} value="SE">South East</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="SO"?"selected":""} value="SO">South</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="SW"?"selected":""} value="SW">South West</option>
        <option ${indv_adr_mail_st_dir=="WE"?"selected":""} value="WE">West</option>
</select>
```